# Does the observation function for POMDP always add up to 1?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process, pomdp

I was reading in the article *[A tutorial on partially observable Markov decision processes](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022249609000042)* (p. 120), by Michael L. Littman, that $\sum_{z \in Z}O(a, s',z) =1$, where $a$ is the action, $s'$ the next possible state and $z$ a certain/specific observation.

How come that the observation function $O(a, s', z)$ adds up to $1$ in POMDP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$O(a, s', z) = \mathbb{P}(z \mid a, s')$ is a [conditional probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution), so it always needs to sum up to $1$. You should interpret $O(a, s', z)$ as the probability of observation $z$, given that the agent took action $a$ and landed in state $s'$.

$O(a, s', z)$ is thus **not** a [joint distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution), even though the notation $O(a, s', z)$ might suggest it. In this case, $O(a, s', z)$ simply means that $O$ is a function of $a$, $z$ and $s'$.

If you want to see a proof that conditional probability distributions sum up to 1, have a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2084313/168764).

Comment: But does it still mean, that I have to observe a state somehow, even the information might not be accurate?

Comment: @BryanMcGill You don't observe any state (in POMDPs). You get "observations", which you use to model your belief in which state you might be in.

Comment: That clarifies everythinga. I came along some illustrations where "observations" were connected to states and I got confused. Maybe you could edit your answer regarding that one sentence in the beginning.